# for loop in R to simulate a password door

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to do a simple for loop to simulate a password door. You get three chances to enter the correct password; otherwise the door will be locked. Here is my code. However, I get an error msg due to NA.

clearly, the code is trying to evaluate the if expression before I input any number on the keyboard. This really confuses me about how for-loop works in R. Could anyone figure out why there is such error msg and how to fix that? Thanks!

```
pw=2497

for (i in 1:3){
  pw_entered=as.numeric(readline("Please enter the password: "))

  if (pw_entered==pw){
    print("The door is opened. Welcome!")
    break
    
  } else {
    print("Password wrong. Please re-enter the password: ")
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me as expected. What input do you enter?

Comment: The first iteration does not ask for my input but rather takes pw_entered as "". Here is my updated code: `pw="2497"

for (i in 1:3){
  
  pw_entered=readline("Please enter the password: ")
  print(pw_entered)
  
  if (pw_entered==pw){
    print("The door is opened. Welcome!")
    break
    
  } else {
    
    if(i!=3){
      print("Please re-enter the password: ")
    } else{
      print("Password wrong. The door is closed due to too many trials.")
    }
    
  }
  
} ` The results looks: Please enter the password: 
[1] ""
[1] "Please re-enter the password: "

Comment: It skips the first iteration of asking password from keyboard and take pw_entered as "".

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change pw to `'2497'` and `remove as.numeric()`:
`pw_entered=readline("Please enter the password: ")`

`as.numeric()` will return `NA` if the input cannot be converted to numeric.

Comment: For some reason, my skips the first iteration of asking password from keyboard and take pw_entered as "".

Comment: The first iteration does not ask for my input but rather takes pw_entered as "". Here is my updated code: pw="2497"  for (i in 1:3){      pw_entered=readline("Please enter the password: ")   print(pw_entered)      if (pw_entered==pw){     print("The door is opened. Welcome!")     break        } else {          if(i!=3){       print("Please re-enter the password: ")     } else{       print("Password wrong. The door is closed due to too many trials.")     }        }    }  The results looks: Please enter the password: [1] "" [1] "Please re-enter the password: "

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.